# jquery var = text + number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icons

I have a bullet list `<ul>` with custom bullet icons. I need some kind of javascript that will go through my list and check if **icon-** has a number after it, if it does than add an `<img>` tag and add the *icon- + number* as a class as each *icon- + number* will be a different icon.

See my code below.

Thanks in advance for your help

**HTML**

```
<ul class="someclass">
  <li>
    <div class="divClass">
      [icon-1]
    </div>
    Some Text
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="divClass">
      [icon-2]
    </div>
    Some Other Text
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript** attempt

```
$(".someclass .divClass").each(function() {    
        var icon = [icon + number]

    $(".divClass:contains('icon')").text().replace('<img class="icon" src="img/path/pic.png" alt="Bullet List Icon" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var i = 1; 
    $(".someclass .divClass").each(function() {  

        var icon = "[icon-" + i++ +"]"; 

    $(".divClass:contains('"+icon+"')").html('<img class="icon" src="img/path/pic.png" alt="Bullet List Icon" />');
});
```

**UPDATE**: Keep the `li` text :

```
var i = 1; 
    $(".someclass li").each(function() {  

        var icon = "[icon-" + i++ +"]"; 
        var liText = $(this).text(); // Get all text of li element
        liText = liText.replace(icon, "");// Remove the [icon-i] string from the text. 
    $(".someclass li:contains('"+icon+"')").html('<img class="icon" src="img/path/pic.png" alt="Bullet List Icon" />'+ liText);
});
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, @DaniP,

Thank you for your quick response.

The code worked beautifully, but I updated my html code to the following:


<ul class="someclass">
  <li>
      [icon-1] Some Text
  </li>

  <li>
      [icon-2] Some Other Text
  </li>
</ul>


Is there a way I can apply a split to the <li> so that when replacing the [icon-1] and [icon-2] the text stays the same?

ex: <img class="icon"> some test.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add a code block format when commenting in StackOverFlow.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmad, you're a life saver lool it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
$('.someclass .divClass').each(function(){
  //Get the actual text of div and remove the '[]'
  var val = $(this).text().replace(/\[|\]/g, "");
  //Check if the string has a number
  if(val.match(/\d+/g) !== null){
    //If true set the class as the prev text and add the img tag
    $(this).addClass(val).html('<img src="http://placehold.it/50"/>');
  }
})
```

```css
.icon-1 {
  background:purple;
}
.icon-2 {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="someclass">
  <li>
    <div class="divClass">
      [icon-1]
    </div>
    Some Text
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="divClass">
      [icon-2]
    </div>
    Some Other Text
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="divClass">
      [icon]
    </div>
    Some Other Text
  </li>
</ul>
```